Can’t synchronize the local changes made to a QField Cloud project
I keep trying to synchronize some local changes made to a Cloud project but I can’t synchronize them. At first, the server let me synchronize them but then, all of a sudden, it started giving me this error:

HITP 500|
https://app.qfield.cloud/api/v1/
deltas/1ce93f2f-2780-4ae4-
b617-0f0363eb2286/ Server
Error.
{"code": "unknown_error", "mess age":"QFieldcloud Unknown
Error"}

I have QField on IOS and I would like to keep the changes and don’t waste them, if I delete the app and not the documents, will I be able to retrieve the local changes again when I reinstall the app?
